# Getting error named 'undefine' when i fetch json data from php page to index page

Tags: php, jquery, json

When I click on an image it opens popup and it will show zoom image but it is not working properly. It shows whole array but it cant display by index.

So how do I fix this problem?

popup.php

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$hidden_id =  $_POST['hidden_id']; 

$sel = "select * from uploaded_images where id='$id' ";
$exe = mysql_query($sel);
$fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe);
echo  json_encode($fet);
```

this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //open popup
    $(".anchor_img").click(function (e) {
        var targetPopup = $(this).attr('id');
        //$(".overlay_form").html("$id="+targetPopup);
        $("#hidden_id").attr('value',targetPopup);
        //$("#myform").submit();
        //var dataStr  =  $("#myform").serialize(); 
        //alert(targetPopup);
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "popup.php?id="+targetPopup,
           dataType : 'JSON',
           data: $('#myform').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
              $(".overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
                //$("#id").html(jsonStr.id);
                 console.log(data.id);

           }

       });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.      
    });

    //close popup
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
    });

});
```

Comment: Paste in your entire error into the question

Comment: It is only show keyword 'undefined' in console

Comment: try to `log` all response like `console.log(data)` and check whether it's returning `id` or not from server

Comment: console.log(data) shows whole array like

Comment: {"id":"80","category_name":"indian_granite","images_path":"uploads\/indian_granite\/1449863747_ind_gra18.jpg","fullpath":"upload\/indian_granite\/"}

Comment: it should be `data['id']` instead of `data.id`

Comment: you are getting data as a string an not as a JS object. I think your "dataType" parameter should be lowercase ("json" instead of "JSON").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the JSON with the proper header from PHP :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo  json_encode($fet);
```

And/or use lowercase parameter value for "dataType" :

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "popup.php?id="+targetPopup,
           dataType : 'json',
           data: $('#myform').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
              $(".overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
                //$("#id").html(jsonStr.id);
                 console.log(data.id);

           }

       });
```